# How to make MySQL order values by BigInteger instead of varchar when column to order by is in case statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 
FROM table_1 join table_2 .... 
ORDER BY
CASE :expression
WHEN 'Column_1' then column_1
WHEN 'Column_2' then column_2
WHEN 'Column_3' then column_3
END asc;
```

which I'm using in my Java code, calling it with native query. 
The table is defined this way:

```
column_1 BIGINT(20)
column_2 VARCHAR(20)
column_3 INT(11)
```

Column 1 holds values from 1 to 9999. When I'm trying to order this query by column 1 my results are ordered like a text. For example:

Expected result:

```
|column_1|
_________
98
99
100
101
...
```

Actual result:

```
|column_1|
_________
100
101
98
99
...
```

Does anyone of you know how to make MySQL sort by column_1 using syntax which I stated and for it to work? I've tried casting, converting, adding 0 and multiplying by 1, to no avail. When I remove cases which have VARCHAR columns in them, the query works perfectly. Unfortunately, when they are present, this happens. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate this into separate `case` expressions:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN :expression = 'Column_1' THEN column_1 END),
         (CASE WHEN :expression = 'Column_2' THEN 'column_2' END),
         (CASE WHEN :expression = 'Column_3' THEN 'Column_3' END)
```

The problem you are facing is caused by type conversion.  The `case` expression returns a single value.  If one of the `THEN` values is a string, then the type conversion rules convert *all* to strings -- which is the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Splitting order by to multiple possibilities worked, thank you for the help.